# Extract domain from URL in Typescript app using new URL() API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I've got a URL containing a lot of params, and I need to extract just the domain name in order to perform a check on that domain name only. The app I'm coding in is a typescript application, it treats URL as a type instead of a string.

Originally I was writing code that was along these lines:

```
const hostnameExample = "http://www.foo.bar.com?search=www.google.com" 
//example of URL I'm trying to get just a domain of

const cleanupParams2 = (url: string) => {
  let domain = new URL(url);
  return domain.hostname;
}
export const isExternalLink = (hostname?: string, goodDomains: string[] = []) => {
  return goodDomains.every((domain) => {
    if (hostname && !hostname.startsWith("#")) {
      return cleanupParams2(hostname).indexOf(domain) < 0;
    }
  });
};
```

I'm getting an error message in my unit test scripts, I really don't even understand the error messages I'm getting or why I'm getting them to be honest.

```
    expect(jest.fn()).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: 0
    Received number of calls: 14

    1: "Invalid URL: www.foo.bar.com·
```

What would be wrong with the source code that it would be throwing an error, and/or what in the world is that error? It's being thrown from basically any file that appears to directly or indirectly be using the isExternalLink function. I know I'm not showing all of the code here, but this is the problematic code basically.

Comment: A URL has to begin `http://something` or `https://something`.  What you supplied was a domain name, not a URL.

Comment: Just a mistake in me asking the question--I am correctly posting a full URL, so I updated the question

Comment: Maybe so, but the error message says you passed it "www.foo.bar.com".   The code calls that variable "hostname", not "hosturl".